# Spacy NER entities postition

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

How can I get the entity position found by NER within spacy?

From the following example:

```
doc = nlp('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in New York')
print(list([(ent for ent in doc.ents])
```

it results:

```
['Rami Eid','Stony Brook University','New York']
```

but I need the position of each entity within the sentence, so that I can know which tokens belong to the respective entity.

If I need to search from these results, I may have some cases where single word entities match multiple words of other entities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An entity is an object of the spacy.Span class, meaning it inherits methods such as *start*, *end* etc.

```
>>> doc = nlp('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in New York')
>>> [(e.start, e.end) for e in doc.ents]
[(0, 2), (5, 8), (9, 11)]
```